# why does my spring boot app first fail and then suddenly start in cloudfoundry?

Tags: spring, tomcat, spring-boot, cloud-foundry

We just migrated four of our apps to spring boot 1.4 and 3 three are running fine. 
The 4th is the only one with WAR packaging and contains JSPs. This one has a very strange behaviour: we push it, then it automatically fails two times to start and then when it gets started by CF the third time it works. Has anyone ever heard about this before? I’m really out of ideas.

To be clear: I only push the app, then cloudfoundry takes care of everything else. It tries to start the app four times until it suddenly succeeds. I don't stop or start the app any other way. Also, the same thing happens when we stop and start the app via CF GUI, without doing a push before...

```
2016-08-15T20:01:14.06+0200 [APP/0]      OUT 18:01:14.063 [Tomcat-startStop-1] ERROR o.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase - A child container failed during start
2016-08-15T20:01:14.06+0200 [APP/0]      OUT java.util.concurrent.ExecutionException: org.apache.catalina.LifecycleException: Failed to start component [StandardEngine[Tomcat].StandardHost[localhost].StandardContext[]]
2016-08-15T20:01:14.06+0200 [APP/0]      OUT    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.report(FutureTask.java:122)
2016-08-15T20:01:14.06+0200 [APP/0]      OUT    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.get(FutureTask.java:192)
2016-08-15T20:01:14.06+0200 [APP/0]      OUT    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.startInternal(ContainerBase.java:911)
2016-08-15T20:01:14.06+0200 [APP/0]      OUT    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHost.startInternal(StandardHost.java:890)
2016-08-15T20:01:14.06+0200 [APP/0]      OUT    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:152)
2016-08-15T20:01:14.06+0200 [APP/0]      OUT    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase$StartChild.call(ContainerBase.java:1403)
2016-08-15T20:01:14.06+0200 [APP/0]      OUT    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase$StartChild.call(ContainerBase.java:1393)
2016-08-15T20:01:14.06+0200 [APP/0]      OUT    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:266)
2016-08-15T20:01:14.06+0200 [APP/0]      OUT    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142)
2016-08-15T20:01:14.06+0200 [APP/0]      OUT    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617)
2016-08-15T20:01:14.06+0200 [APP/0]      OUT    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
2016-08-15T20:01:14.06+0200 [APP/0]      OUT Caused by: org.apache.catalina.LifecycleException: Failed to start component [StandardEngine[Tomcat].StandardHost[localhost].StandardContext[]]
2016-08-15T20:01:14.06+0200 [APP/0]      OUT    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:158)
2016-08-15T20:01:14.06+0200 [APP/0]      OUT    ... 6 common frames omitted
2016-08-15T20:01:14.06+0200 [APP/0]      OUT Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException: null
2016-08-15T20:01:14.06+0200 [APP/0]      OUT    at org.apache.tomcat.util.scan.StandardJarScanner.process(StandardJarScanner.java:325)
2016-08-15T20:01:14.06+0200 [APP/0]      OUT    at org.apache.tomcat.util.scan.StandardJarScanner.scan(StandardJarScanner.java:182)
2016-08-15T20:01:14.06+0200 [APP/0]      OUT    at org.apache.jasper.servlet.TldScanner.scanJars(TldScanner.java:262)
2016-08-15T20:01:14.06+0200 [APP/0]      OUT    at org.apache.jasper.servlet.TldScanner.scan(TldScanner.java:104)
2016-08-15T20:01:14.06+0200 [APP/0]      OUT    at org.apache.jasper.servlet.JasperInitializer.onStartup(JasperInitializer.java:103)
2016-08-15T20:01:14.06+0200 [APP/0]      OUT    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.startInternal(StandardContext.java:5167)
2016-08-15T20:01:14.06+0200 [APP/0]      OUT    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:152)
2016-08-15T20:01:14.06+0200 [APP/0]      OUT    ... 6 common frames omitted
```

for the complete logs, please see: http://pastebin.com/6pqtbH7F

edit: I just made a test with the Spring Boot JSP example (https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-boot/tree/master/spring-boot-samples/spring-boot-sample-tomcat-jsp) and it shows the exact same problem.

Comment: I created an issue for spring-boot: https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-boot/issues/6657

Answer (score 3, accepted):

this is an incompatibility issue with tomcat 8.5.4 https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-boot/issues/6657

Answer (score 0):

Given the full log you posted, it looks like your application is running out of resource on CF. Could you post the output of the following command:

`cf events <app name>`

Comment: Glad to see you found the cause!